# Passing data attributes with ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I want pass some extra data into the controller from `ui-sref`. I am looping a json object and adding data to the sref: `<a data-imgName="{{ img.name }}" data-imgDesc="{{ img.desc }}" ui-sref="main.imgDesc({imgid: '{{ img.id }}'})">`

```
$stateProvider.state('main.imgDesc', {
        url: '/image/:imgid',
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: 'ImageDescCtrl'
    });
```

I want `imgName` and `imgDesc` into the controller. I have checked `$state` but its not found in it. Is there any way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We should use `params : {}` to declare any kind of parameter, even complex object:

```
$stateProvider.state('main.imgDesc', {
    url: '/image/:imgid',
    templateUrl: '...',
    controller: 'ImageDescCtrl',
    params: {
       imageData: null,
    }
});
```

And we are ready to pass those

```
ui-sref="main.imgDesc({imgid: img.id, imageData: img })"
```

and controller can ask for `$stateParams` where both will be available *(if passed as above)*

Answer (score 1):

Using params,

Html

```
ui-sref="main.img({imageId: img.id, imageData: img })"
```

Controller

```
$stateProvider.state('main.img', {
url: '/image/:imgid',
templateUrl: '...',
controller: 'ImageDescCtrl',
params: {
   imgData: null,
}
});
```